# Rails + PostgreSQL: How to query timezone info along with time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

I'm using Rails4 and PostgreSQL v9.6.2, my problem is that I want to process `datetime`s in Rails in the timezone that it was entered, it gets stored properly in PostreSQL but when I retrieve it with Rails the timezone info gets lost.

I'm using a `timestamp with time zone` in PostgreSQL and `datetime` in Rails. For example, while on PostgreSQL I see `2012-10-26 19:26:00+02`, on Rails I'm getting `Fri, 26 Oct 2012 17:26:00 UTC +00:00`, which is technically the same date, but on UTC, or without the original timezone. I'd want to get, from Rails, the timezone info stored on PostgreSQL.

Comment: You should do like this `Model.group("DATE_TRUNC('day', created_at)").count`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this :(

Comment: you can use [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) with`datetime_field.strftime('%F %R %z')` . It will return something like `2018-02-13 14:02 +0200`

Comment: It still doesn't get the timezone info from PosgreSQL, it returns the time in UTF: `"2012-10-26 17:26 +0000"`

Answer (score 1):

From Postgres manual:

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
> UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
> Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
> converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
> no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
> in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is
> converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.
>
> When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always
> converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as
> local time in that zone. To see the time in another time zone, either
> change timezone or use the AT TIME ZONE construct

You can override current time zone on a session level using:

```
SET TIME ZONE timezone;
```

where *timezone* your desired time zone.

Comment: Not sure that really asks my question, what I'd want is to get the `+0200` bit from a date like this: `2018-02-13 14:02 +0200`, when I query it from Rails, and that for an individual element. As I could have elements with `+0200` and others with `+0100`, regardless of the timezone of the session or the user.

Comment: @JoaoTorres I think there is some misunderstanding. What do you mean saying: "I'd want to get, from Rails, the timezone info stored on PostgreSQL"?

Comment: @JoaoTorres I think you're misunderstanding this slightly, the timezone of the server is always the same, regardless of the timezone of the currently signed in user of your web app. The value you see in postgres is just a representation of the stored UTC value.

Comment: @IvanMogila I need to show the time of a specific element on the timezone it was entered, so when I have different elements in different timezones, "I'd want to get, from Rails, the timezone info stored on PostgreSQL".

So for example, say I have two different elements stored with the following dates: `2018-02-13 14:02 +0200` and `2018-02-13 13:02 +0100`, both are interpreted by Rails as the same value as it takes into account the set timezone, and not the timezone value stored in PostgreSQL, which on the first one was `+0200` and the second `+0100`.

Comment: @Iceman I get that the timezone of the server is always the same (and a single value), the issue is that PostgreSQL stores on each `timestamp with timezone` a timezone value. Ideally, I'd like to get, in Rails, both values and not a single value on the server timezone, as if I have elements with different timezones, that information is lost on the Rails query. Is that clearer? I get it's a specific use case, but that's what I need right now.

Comment: @JoaoTorres Postgres do not store original time zone for `timestamp with timezone` values. It converts any input values to UTC. There is no way you can get these values back in its original time zone unless you explicitly specify time zone using `AT TIME ZONE` construct or `SET TIME ZONE`.